# Write something in a process and read it in another

Tags: c, fork

I want to write something in process A and read it in process B which is forked by A. But I find that B cannot read the content unless A is terminated. How can I write in process A while read in B without A quitting? My code is as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int mypipe[2];

int main(){
    FILE* f;
    pid_t pid = 0;
    int num = 0, temp;

    pipe(mypipe);

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == (pid_t)0){
        f = fdopen(mypipe[0], "r");
        while (1){
            fscanf(f, "%d", &temp);
            printf("from child: %d\n", temp);
        }
        fclose(f);
    }
    else{
        f = fdopen(mypipe[1], "w");
        while (1){
            scanf("%d", &num);
            fprintf(f, "%d\n", num);
            //break;
        }
        fclose(f);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `stdio` streams (`FILE *`) are buffered. Either use *raw* read/write operations your OS provides or try `fflush()` after each write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> B cannot read the content unless A is terminated

This is because A doesn't actually write something. `stdio` streams (represented by `FILE *`) are buffered. You can set the buffering mode using [`setvbuf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf). The stream you open on your pipe with `fdopen()` will be *fully buffered* by default, so no actual writes to the pipe occur until the buffer is full.

The easiest solution is to put a call to [`fflush()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) in your code anywhere you want writes to occur, e.g. in your code directly after the `fprintf()`:

```
    while (1){
        scanf("%d", &num);
        fprintf(f, "%d\n", num);
        fflush(f);
        //break;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are many unnecessary lines in your code. Instead of doing fdopen() you can directly use read() and write() system calls. Secondly fork() system call return 0 to the child and pid of the child process to the parent. Finally parent should wait for child to finish and clear it from memory to stop it becoming zombie.

This is the corrected version of your code works perfectly without break.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
   int status;   // To get return status of file
   // No need of FILE pointer
   int mypipe[2];  // No need to make it global
   pid_t pid = 0;
   int num = 0, temp;

   pipe(mypipe); // Create pipe

   if((pid = fork()) == 0)   // Child block
   {
      close(mypipe[1]);   // Child will close the writing end

      while (1)
      {
          read(mypipe[0],&temp,sizeof(int));
          printf("from child: %d\n",temp);
      }
      exit(0);  // Exit the child
   }
   else     // Parent block
   {
      close(mypipe[0]);   // Parent will close the reading end of pipe
      while (1)
      {
          scanf("%d", &num);
          write(mypipe[1],&num,sizeof(int));
      }
   }

   // Parent should wait for child
   wait(&status);
   return 0;
}
```

Read the system calls man pages 
man 2 read, man 2 write etc.

Comment: "*Instead of doing fdopen() you can directly use read() and write() system calls.*" <- not really, if you want formatting and other comfort provided by `stdio`. Also, it's often a good idea to limit the platform-specific code to a minimum.

Comment: You can do the same using read() write() system calls and sprintf(), sscanf()  for formatting. i do not think other this any thing else is needed

Comment: That's unnecessarily complicated. If you need formatting, just use a standard `FILE *` stream. Furthermore, `read()` and `write()` (as well as `fdopen()`) aren't standard C but are provided by POSIX systems. Using them isn't portable and you might have to replace them by different functions for different systems. If all you do with a pipe is `fdopen()` its ends, the rest of your code stays standard C and porting only means you have to replace the code that gives you your `FILE *`.

Comment: pipe is also a system call which takes kernels help to do the work. so if you are using pipe() then there should be no problem in using read() write() because internally printf() FILE I/O does the same thing that is invoke system calls. And how can you format standard FILE* stream. If your need conversion from char to int or vice versa then sscanf, sprintf will be needed there also.

Comment: And by the way POSIX means Portable operating system interface so if they are provided by POSIX then they must be portable.

Comment: Tell this the world of `HANDLE`, `CreatePipe()`, etc. It's easier to abstract just creating the pipe into a platform-dependent module than all the read and write accesses as well. Using `stdio` as much as you can is always good for easy portability.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you guys' discussions! They do help me.